# Number of processes of /bin/bash is 2 when it should be 1

Tags: bash

I'm using Tilix. When I open a new terminal, it opens in the `~/` directory (when sometimes I'm like 10 layers in).

I came up with this code (which I put in my `~/.bashrc` file):

```sh
function cd() {
    builtin cd $1 && pwd > ~/.last_dir
}

if [ ! -f ~/.last_dir ]
then
    pwd > ~/.last_dir
else
    cd $(cat ~/.last_dir)
fi

function end() {
    if [ -f ~/.last_dir ]
    then
        pid_n=$(pgrep -c bash)

        echo $pid_n > ~/test.txt

        if [[ $pid_n -eq 1 ]]
        then 
            rm ~/.last_dir
        fi
    fi
}

trap end EXIT
```

The thing is: when I have only one terminal open and I execute `exit` I get that the file `~/test.txt` has the value 2 in it (and if I have 2 terminals open and I close one, I got a 3, and so on).

When I'm executing `pgrep -c bash` or `ps -C bash --no-headers | wc -l` in the terminal I get the correct number though, which is strange.

If someone could help me, it would be awesome!

**Specs**:

- Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
- Tilix version: 1.7.7-1ubuntu2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash executes the [command substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) of `$()` in a [subshell](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html#SUBSHELLSREF), which is the extra bash process you have seen.